# Yii2 GridView display only related records

Tags: mysql, yii2, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have this database structure:
[image: database model]

I need the user to get only those reservations in ReservationsSeachModel that are in the warehouse belonging to the user. Model user_has_warehouse has a function getUserHasWarehouse($user_id, $warehouse_id) to check for relations. I am able to get the relations when viewing single, deleting and updating records in controllers. But I cannot make the SearchModel to return reservations that belong to current user.
I cannot depend on Reservation->user_id, because that value is not mandatory and reservations can be inserted publicly with no user_id. How to make the SearchModel work properly so it only shows reservations belonging to the warehouse where user has the warehouse?

ReservationsSearchModel:

```
$warehouse_id = User_Has_Warehouse::find()->select(['warehouse_id'])->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);
    $freezer_type_id = Freezer_type::find()->select(['id'])->where(['warehouse_id' => $warehouse_id]);
    $reservation_id = Reservation_freezer_type::find()->select(['reservation_id'])->where(['freezer_type_id'=>$freezer_type_id]);
...
$query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $reservation_id,
        'customer_id' => $this->customer_id,
        'user_id' => $this->user_id,
    ]);
```

...

But the following did not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have added some more code with my approach.

Comment: Have you read [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#relational-data)?

Comment: While working all the way back from the warehouse I have managed to solve the problem. Hope it helps someone too. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Managed to solve it.**

```
$h = User_Has_Warehouse::find()->select(['warehouse_id'])->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id]);
$rt = Freezer_type::find()->select(['id'])->where(['warehouse_id' => $h]);
$res = Reservation_freezer_type::find()->select(['reservation_id'])->where(['freezer_type_id' => $rt]);

// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere(['id' => $res]);
```